# I can't run react-native run-android

Tags: android, emulator

I'd try to run `react-native run-android`
but it always fails and appears error like this:

JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().

> Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug

```
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (/Users/jworotikan/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:299:19)
    at buildAndRun (/Users/jworotikan/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:135:12)
    at isPackagerRunning.then.result (/Users/jworotikan/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:65:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Please Help me, how to solve this. I'm Using Mac and running Android Emulator from Android Studio.

Comment: You might get a better response to this on our sister site [android.se].

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Mac, then it may be a permission error.

try this on your project using a terminal:

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew && react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the process: run:

   `ps aux | grep react-native`
2. Kill the process:

   `sudo kill -9 14492`(pid)
3. Run project

   `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`

Note: Watchman reset cache: If the above steps do not work, please

```
sudo npm start -- --reset-cache
```